# Can an enumerator be defined in terms of other enumerators within the same enum type?

Tags: c++, c, enums

For the sake of curiosity, I am experimenting this:

```
enum RxqType
{
    A = (1 << 0),
    B = (1 << 1),
    C = (A | B),
    D = A+B+C
};
```

Enumerator C and D are defined in terms of earlier enumerators. It is unusual so I am not sure whether it is safe. I can find no example about it through Google (maybe overlook though).

It seems to be fine when I `printf` or `cout` `C` and `D` on Visual C++ 2013 and MinGW. But I am worrying whether it is standard conforming, and whether it triggers undefined behaviours.

Can anyone answer to my worry about standard conformance and undefined behaviour? And is there anything else I have to concern?

Comment: an example from C++ std: `enum { d, e, f=e+2 };`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz Oh, I should remember to look up the standard(s) before the next question.

Comment: @PiotrNycz Strictly speaking, examples aren't normative. Although it is of course unlikely that the standard contains examples which aren't compliant.

Comment: @Lundin, "Compliant with the standard" and "a good idea" aren't _necessarily_ the same thing. ;) (No comment indented on whether this kind of syntax is a good/bad idea, just that library code isn't always written with best practices.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
enum RxqType
{
    A = (1 << 0),
    B = (1 << 1),
    C = (A | B),
    D = A+B+C
};
```

In C and in  C++ this is valid.

For C:

> (C11, 6.2.1p7) "Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list."

For C++:

> (C++11, 3.3.2p4) "The point of declaration for an enumerator is immediately after its enumerator-definition."

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.2.1` *Scopes of identifiers* which which tells us each enumerator is in scope after it is defined:

> Each enumeration constant has scope that
>   begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list.

This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `3.3.2` *Point of declaration* which says:

> The point of declaration
>   for an enumeration is immediately after the identifier (if any) in either its enum-specifier (7.2) or its first
>   opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), whichever comes first.

and for completeness sake we can go to section `6.7.2.2` *Enumeration specifiers* of the draft C99 standard,  which tells us an enumerator can be set by a constant expression and an enumerator itself is a constant expression.

```
enumerator:
    enumeration-constant
    enumeration-constant = constant-expression
```

What are constant expression is covered in section `6.6` *Constant expressions* and it tells us that enumerators are constants and also that arithmetic expressions of integer constants are also constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Although as noted already, it is perfectly valid, there is one thing you have to look out for: while an enumeration type is being defined, in C++, the already-declared enumerators may not have the exact type you're expecting. As a result, something like

```
enum E {
  a = INT_MAX,
  b = UINT_MAX,
  c = a + 1, // error: overflow
};
```

is not valid, even though this is:

```
enum E {
  a = INT_MAX,
  b = UINT_MAX,
};
enum E2 {
  c = a + 1, // okay: a is promoted to unsigned int
};
```

For a similar example, overload resolution may not behave like you would expect:

```
char f(int);
template <typename T>
char (&f(T))[2];

enum E {
  a = 0,
  b = sizeof(f(a)), // 1
};
enum E2 {
  c = sizeof(f(a)), // 2
};
```

There are other similar examples that are somewhat unintuitive.

For C, the rules are a bit simpler. In C, an enumeration constant's type is independent of the enumeration type, so my example of `a + 1` is invalid even with the `E2`. This does lead do consistent results.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, 100% valid. This is just fine, in fact, appreciated.

```
enum RxqType
{
    A = (1 << 0),
    B = (1 << 1),
    C = (A | B),
    D = A+B+C
};
```

Comment: "Can anyone answer to my worry about standard conformance and undefined behaviour?"